# What is the probability that exactly one event will occur if...

Tags: probability-theory

Two events $A$ and $B$ have probabilities respectively of $p(A)$ and $p(B)$.

> What is the probability that exactly one event will occur if
>
> 1. $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive
> 2. $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive, but dependent
> 3. $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive, but independent

Attempt:

1. $P(A)+P(B)$
2. $P(A)P(B^c)+P(B)P(A^c)$
3. $P(A\cap B^c)+P(A^c\cap B)$

Comment: You mixed 2 and 3, and the independent case could be simplified a bit

Comment: $P(A \cap B^c) + P(A^c \cap B)$ is true for all three, but in case (2) it can't be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

1. $ P(A\cap B^c) + P(B\cap A^c) 
   = P(A) + P(B) $
2. $P(A\cap B^c) + P(B\cap A^c) 
   =  P(A\cup B) - P(A\cap B) $
3. $P(A\cap B^c) + P(B\cap A^c) 
   =  P(A\cup B) - P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A)P(B)$